# .vbs won't execute anything at all

Tags: windows, batch, windows-server-2008, vbscript

I created short script to run .bat file on background but when i execute .vbs file, it seems like it is not reading my script at all.
.Dos windows pops up and shutdown right away but my batch file is never executed.
(when i execute batch file directly, it works fine, so I'm assuming this script is the problem)

```
Dim sCurPath
sCurPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".")
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmds=WshShell.RUN(sCurPath & "\myrun.bat", 0, True)
```

This code works on my desktop, windows 7 32 bit but when i try to execute this script on windows server 2008 R2, it won't do anything.
Does anyone know what I need to do to run this .vbs script on windows server?

Comment: are you using csript or wscript to execute the .vbs?

Comment: what do you mean? i just have .vbs file and i'm just clicking .vbs file to execute, which works on my desktop but not server computer

Comment: @Keltari Nvm, it is running in wscript on my desktop

Answer (score 2):

Most admins disable WSH on Windows Server

Verify the entry values located below are set to 1 (enabled):

User:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings\Enabled
```

Machine:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Script Host\Settings\Enabled
```

[TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198684.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment, it would appear you were trying to WSH script in the command shell script environment.  These are not interchangeable.  It would appear you are using the right script host now.